# Contact Structure on $\mathbb{P}(V)$

Tags: complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $V$ be a complex vector space of dimension $2n$, with a nondegenerate $2-$form $\omega$. Then the differential form $\alpha_v(-)=\omega(v,-)$ at $v\in\mathbb{P}(V)$ is a (local) contact form on $\mathbb{P}(V)$.

I want to show that $d\imath_v\omega=\omega$ then I can get the result, but I cannot show this. Suppose I take a vector space of dimension $2$, and I take the form to be $dz_1\wedge dz_2$, then I take $v=(1,0)$, so I get $d\imath_v\omega(v)=0$. I think I make a mistake somewhere, can someone figure it out?

Updated: I find out the above one is not a problem as the space is one dimensional. So I should say this: take $V$ to be dimension $2n$, and $\omega=\sum dx_i\wedge dy_i$, where $dx_i,dy_i$ are holomorphic. Then WLOG suppose $v=(1,0,...,0)$, which is dual to $dx_1$. Then $d\imath_v\omega(v)=0$.

Comment: This is a bit unclear to me. It doesn't seem that $\alpha_v$ is even well-defined, since $\omega(v,\cdot)$ depends on the choice of representative for $v$ (which is a $1$-dim subspace of $V$). Up to scalar, of course.

Comment: @IvoTerek Is it fine if we take the form up to scalar? This is from Page 260 of Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry I by Voisin.

Comment: I'm not sure, because the scalar depends on the line, so you actually have a function times $\omega$. I can try to check the book tomorrow.

Comment: @IvoTerek Thank you very much. I am thinking whether we fix the length of the vector first. Take your time.

Comment: Just to make sure this is the real projective space?

Comment: @ArcticChar It is complex projective space.

Comment: What is the definition of a contact form? I thought it has to be on an odd dimensional manifold.

Comment: @ArcticChar You are right in classical setting. Here for contact we mean holomorphic contact. A form $\alpha$ is said to be contact if $\alpha\wedge(d\alpha)^n$ does not vanish at any point. This is kind of holomorphic analogue.

Comment: Um I am getting more confused. Is $\omega = \sum dx^i \wedge dy^i$ nondegenerate if $x, y$ are the holomorphic coordiantes? It seems that $\omega (v, \partial_{\bar x_i}) = 0$ for all $v$

Comment: @ArcticChar If I understand correctly, we just consider holomrophic coordinate, as the form we assume is in $\alpha\wedge(d\alpha)^n\in K_X$

Comment: $\alpha \wedge (d\alpha)^n$ is a form with odd degree, how could it be in $K_X$?

Comment: @ArcticChar $X$ is an odd (complex) dimensional manifold, so it is in $K_X$. Here $K_X$ is the top holomorphic differential.

Comment: I assume that $X = \mathbb P(V)$, so $K_X$ is not trivial, and any section on $K_X$ must have zero.

Comment: @ArcticChar You are right in global sense. This question is asking locally, locally $K_X$ can have sections, otherwise even global $1-$form does not exist by Euler sequence. I will add this point in the problem.